In groovy main method how do I use evaluate method to load and execute a static class defined in another groovy file
I'm trying to import a class defined in a different groovy file using evaluate method, please view the snippet or the contents of the file(s) which defines the class and tries to use evaluate method to execute the class as follows
// File: sample.groovy
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    String getFullName() {
        return "$firstName $lastName"
    }

    def addMarksInSubjects(a, b){
        return a+b;
    }
}

I'm calling Person class in a different groovy file under Main class as follows
// runfile.groovy
// Load the Person class from sample.groovy
evaluate(new File('sample.groovy'))

class Main {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an instance of Person
        def person = new Person(firstName: 'Stack', lastName: 'Overflow')

        // Use the method from the Person class
        println "Full Name: ${person.getFullName()}"
    }
}

the folder structure is simple
.
├── runcode.groovy
└── sample.groovy

During compilation I'm encountering the following error which suggests my usage is not applicable for static void main(String[] args) and sadly I'm not sure as to how to proceed further.
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static Person.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), any(), find(), wait(long, int), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static Person.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), any(), find(), wait(long, int), any(groovy.lang.Closure)

Please Note:

The reason for using evaluate method in my approach is based on logical inference that evaluate method could dynamically execute the script stored in a file in the current context. Please let me know of any suitable resolution which would be helpful
Some baseline research led me to the following answer here , sadly it is entirely not clear.


you can use native groovy class loader. name file with Person class - Person.gooovy. then running code with command groovy -cp . runcode.groovy - will find/load class by file name in directory . (current dir) without any additional code.

evaluate is a wrapper around return script.run(). Running a class requires it to have a main method, which you don't have, thus the error. In your example it would make more sense to use parseClass():
def clazz = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(new File('sample.groovy'))
println clazz.newInstance() 

It might or might not be what you want, but based on your example this is how you can get it to work.
